# Bot message order issue

Tags: azure-bot-service

When sending multiple messages at once on the bot, it does not preserve the order in which they were sent.
For example, If i have to send 2 separate messages:
1. Hi, I am market bot.
2. How can I help you ?

On occasion the order comes out to be:
2. How can I help you ? 
1. Hi, I am market bot.

Comment: can you please add more details about the channel that you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

If your facing ordering problems with two text messages it's related to the specific channel.

Answer (score 0):

The BotFramework guarantees that activities are sent in the order in which they are generated. Beyond that, it is channel specific meaning it is entirely up to the channel in question to manage how it receives the activities.

If two or more activities are arriving (near) simultaneously in the channel and they are displaying out of order, then there is something in the way that channel is processes the incoming activities that is affecting them.

If you can avoid sending the messages "at once", then consider breaking them up. For instance, you are essentially sending a "welcome" message followed by the beginning of your dialog flow. Look over the [13.core-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot) sample that does just this but as separate actions. This is a slightly more complicated sample (there is a simpler "welcome" sample that demonstrates just the welcome message), but this one also shows how to start the following dialog flow (which the simpler one does not).

Hope of help!